# Removing images that a user has clicked on

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a memory matching game. I have some code that checks if two images that the user clicked on have the same source and removes the images if they do have the same source.

```
(function compareClicked() {
    var lastclicked = "";
    $("img").click(function() {
        var path = $(this).attr("src");
        if( lastclicked == path) {
            $('img').hide(1000, function () {
            $(this).remove();
             });
        }
        else {
            if( lastclicked != "") alert("Not a match");
        }
        lastclicked = path;
    });
})();
```

However, as you can see, when they have the same source, it removes all of the images on the page - even if the user did not click any them. How can I change it so it only removes the two images that the user clicked on?

Comment: your problem is in `$('img').hide`, your selecting all the images, not the one youve clicked.. you want to do `$(this).hide`, `this` referring to the img you've just clicked and the context of the function

Comment: You can use `.attr` on the clicked image to find it later on easily.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help. However, this would only remove one image. I am looking for it to remove both of the images that have the same source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like

```
var lastEl = null;

$(document).ready(function(){

$('img').each(function(index){
  $(this).attr('id','img-' + index);
});    

$('img').click(function(){
  if( lastEl ) {
    if( ($(this).attr('src') == lastEl.attr('src')) && ($(this).attr('id') != lastEl.attr('id')) ) {
      $(this).remove();
      lastEl.remove();
    }
    lastEl = null;
  } else {
    lastEl = $(this);
  }
});

});
```

Haven't tested that, but it's got to be pretty close

EDIT: Updated code in line with conversation below. JS fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/joevallender/pc3Qa/3/

EDIT again: JS fiddle link should be correct now

Comment: I don't know who gave you -1 but this should work good, the only matter is you should check is that `$(this) != lastEl`

Comment: thanks, maybe they noticed I'd missed the global that I am just adding ;-)

Comment: Also, in case it's not clear I'm following the classic pattern of card 1, find match on card 2, yes/no, reset.

Comment: Sorry Michael, I was too busily trying to get the fiddle link up, I'll correct it now

Comment: I've added that check, but it's still removing on two clicks of the same one http://jsfiddle.net/joevallender/pc3Qa/2/ any ideas?

Comment: Wow, thank you guys so much, I really appreciate it. I was thinking about this same issue. What if I were to assign different id's to each  image and have a check if the id's are different and the srcs are the same then nothing would happen. Think that could work?

Comment: You know... you can mark this accepted ;-) I'm pretty sure it's correct after my various amends

Answer (score 6):

```
var lastclicked = "";
$("img").click(function() {
    var path = $(this).attr("src"); // or this.src
    if (lastclicked == path) {
        $(this).hide(1000, function() {
            // remove image with same src as lastClicked
            $('img[src="' + lastclicked + '"]').remove();
        });
    } else {
        if (lastclicked != "") alert("Not a match");
    }
    lastclicked = path;
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/353/)**

Comment: That would work only if he has 2 of the same Src. But let say he got 6 "suns" in his game, that will remove all 6.

Comment: @MichaelLaffargue yup, But from the question, I think OP has not such issue.

Comment: Sorry to be a nag, but this still only removes the last clicked image.

Comment: @Kreacher please check my fiddle and comment if you have some issue

Answer (score 2):

If you got multiple time (more than twice) the same Src, I really suggest that you `tag` your clicked images to know which one should be hidden.
As mentionned you could use `attr` or special `class` for this purpose.

Comment: You are right! But I think that because of the context, a memory matching game, there isn't going to be more than twice the same src

Comment: @OscarSan Well it depends of the game ;) Already seen a lot of matching game with multiple combination.